# iterate over a set cause a coredump

Tags: stl, segmentation-fault, set

I got a problem,my program coredumped when i iterator a set,the code is below,when the size of the set is below 50000,it runs okay,while it'll fail when the size is bigger than 50000(almost).I did nothing in the for loops,but it still coredumped .what is the problem?

```
set<CRoute *>::iterator it = route_list.begin();
for(; it != route_list.end(); ++it)
{
    //Nothing TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the problem?

It's impossible to say given the data you've provided.

There are several common causes:

- You have corrupted the `set` earlier in the program (e.g. by accessing it from multiple threads without proper locking)
- You have used a sorting predicate that violates strict [weak ordering requirements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering) of the `std::set`
- You have left a dangling pointer in your `std::set`, and your sorting predicate uses the dangling data and crashes when given garbage.

To figure out what's happening, [quit thinking and look](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/debugging-agans.html) e.g. by running the program in a debugger and understanding exactly *where* the coredump is happening.